# gtest - composing EXPECT_NO_THROW and EXPECT_EQ

Tags: googletest

I need to use EXPECT_NO_THROW and EXPECT_EQ for the function which returns some value. Here is my solution:

```
int value = 0;
EXPECT_NO_THROW(value = GetValue());
EXPECT_EQ(value, 99);
```

Is there any other way to compose EXPECT_NO_THROW and EXPECT_EQ ?

Comment: Your solution is as good as it gets

Answer (score 0):

Looks a bit ugly, but it seems you may nest one in another:
EXPECT_NO_THROW(EXPECT_EQ(99, GetValue()));

Please notice that in case exception is thrown output print is less straight forward.